# how to use the returned value of the count in sql

Tags: sql, count, sql-update

I am trying to use the value retuned by count in the update statement. But getting the syntax error. Subqueries are working. But the update query is not working. What change is required to get the correct result?

```
update Items set numberOfBids = count (select * from Bids where id ='1673078805') where id='1673078805';    
Error: near "select": syntax error


sqlite> select * from Bids where id ='1673078805';
1673078805|brettgodfrey|14.52|2001-12-05 10:40:41
1673078805|gardnerstoys|15.04|2001-12-06 07:40:41
1673078805|tallulahbankhead|14.01|2001-12-04 13:40:41
1673078805|tgrhino@home.com|15.55|2001-12-07 04:40:41
1673078805|yesterdaysgem|16.06|2001-12-08 01:40:41


sqlite> update Items set numberOfBids = 5 where id='1673078805';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the *count* into the subquery:

```
update Items 
set numberOfBids = 
    ( select count(*) 
      from Bids 
      where id ='1673078805' )
where id='1673078805';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL:

```
UPDATE Items 
SET numberOfBids = (SELECT count(*) 
                    FROM Bids 
                    WHERE id ='1673078805') 
WHERE id='1673078805';
```